# Java: reading compression ratio of an jpeg/gif

Tags: java, jpeg, gif, javax.imageio

I try to get the compression ratio of an JPEG and GIF image in Java.
Searched everywhere but cant find anything. Is it possible to read the compression ratio of the files?
When not how could i compute this ratio?

Comment: Are you referring to quality settings? GIF has no quality settings - it's a lossless format (as long as you don't need more than 256 colors). Jpeg actually has several variables which represent trade-offs between quality and filesize, even though most image editors hide them all behind a single slider.

Comment: Apparently there is no unified definition of "compressions ratio" for JPEG: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88167/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-compression-ratio-was-used-for-a-particular-jpeg

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the compression of an image you compare the actual file size to the size you'd get if you were storing the image "raw".

For example a jpeg file that's 1024x1024, true color (24bpp) that's 384Kb you'd get a ratio of (384x1024) / (1024x1024x3) = 0.125, this means the jpeg produced a file that's 12% of raw image. If you invert the division you can say the image was compressed 8x or 1:8 ratio.

Get the size and color info of the image from headers or by using Image API, no need to decompress the file to do this calculation

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [Java Image-IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html), read in your image and use the appropriate methods of the [ImageReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html) class.

You can download the [JAI here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try comparing the filesize to it's pixels count - it gives you a sort of ratio. For example:

```
//Image 1
Image Dimensions = 607x800px
Number of pixels = 486K
File size = 143KB
//Good quality

//Image 2
Image Dimension s= 1719x2377px
Number pixels= 4.086M
File size = 408KB
//Bad quality
```